# locastorage problem whiling using react js

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, local-storage

how to store div after updating useState value whose doesnot disappearing after getting refresh
in react js .This is concept is mostly used in todoList where item doesnot got wiped. please help me out in this devs . #localstorage-in-js